# ReactNative app when compiled for Mac gets error AssetsLibrary is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to build and iPad app for mac platform which is built on react-native platform.
while compiling the code i am getting error

> AssetsLibrary is deprecated and is not available when building for Mac
> Catalyst.Consider migrating to Photos instead, or use `#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST`to conditionally import this framework, first
> importing TargetConditionals.h if necessary.

I am getting this error in **react-native-image-picker => ImagePickerManager.m**

On this line

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

I am using Xcode 12.1.1 mac target is 10.15

Comment: *"The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Instead, use the Photos framework instead, ..."*

Comment: I know... assetlibrary is part of reactnative image picker library.  not my app's code ... thanks